# Important physical models other than the harmonic oscillator?

Tags: soft-question, harmonic-oscillator, models

Are there any other models used in physics that are as intuitive and mathematically accessible as the harmonic oscillator that can be used to describe a wide range of phenomena?

Comment: Some ideas: Ideal Gas , Hydrogen Atom , 2 level quantum system